# Align button and text in responsive column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Full page width grab:
[image]

Grab of single column within which layout is required:
[image]

This is part of a page level col-sm-4. Then I add another row within that for alignment.

I need the button to stay right aligned - and the text to stay left in a block like that (not to have the button amongst the text).

I can use col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 for this and it works well until we get to the narrowest non mobile size. Then the button is too wide for that column and it spills outside the div.

I am looking for an elegant solution here - perhaps something not using columns. Columns aren't really relevant - I just want the text to come within, say, 20px of the button at any width.

I can't find anything on Google - I'm not really even sure what to search for.

What would be a best practice, responsive friendly approach?

The below code uses the column approach (which seems flawed):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
    Article to go in here and can
    go over two lines if needed
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default btnlight" type="submit">Read more</button>
</div>
```

fig1:
[image]

Comment: can u share your code?

Comment: done - code shared above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

http://plnkr.co/edit/oZ2ActtFiSaaaCvK23gM?p=preview

```
<style>
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .text-holder {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 20px; // you will have 20px always of the button
    }

    .button-holder {
      float: right;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="text-holder">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>

    <div class="button-holder">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8">
      Article to go in here and can
      go over two lines if needed
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-default btnlight" type="submit">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

so for small window size (768px ~ 992px) button will have bigger container.

Comment: This doesn't work. Don't forget it is all within a col-sm-4 in the main page. This code brings the contents inside the col-sm-4 to the full page width.

Comment: if the button is too wide for col-sm-4, than use <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8"> and <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4"> so button will have bigger col-sm-5 container

Comment: Can you explain more please.

Comment: that is why i proposed you use your own holder classes at the beginning. Or try to customize bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ for more @grids. So you will have more control over the size of the cols.

Comment: thanks - did you forget to apply your classes - or are they no longer relevant to this example?

Comment: they are not relevant to the second example. In the second one I used only bootstrap classes.

Comment: It doesn't work - how do I paste a screen shot of what happens?

Comment: It's weird - it largely works. However, the first line of text at 768px ~ 992px goes over the top of the button

Comment: it's difficult to say about your problem without seeing the code.

Comment: are you sure that it is not less than 768px window size ?

Comment: totally sure - at the mobile width it goes to block level - which is fine. It's just that first line of text - very strange

Comment: it seems that you have some custom float styles there.

Comment: Found it! There was some text in that containing <div> that was outside the example code. Got it - thanks a lot.

Comment: great job. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

check out this code

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    Article to go in here and can
    go over two lines if needed
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-default btnlight" type="submit">Read more</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/42nod42d/

Comment: You can see the same problem there - at a certain point the button becomes too wide for the column

Comment: @niico button remain the same width no resize on width. u need the button to look still small for mobile device?

Comment: The button remains the same width - but the column is narrower at a narrower width - and spills outside the column

Comment: This is not happening at mobile width - but at the narrowest non mobile width

Comment: Essentially I thin you're going down the same road as yuyokk - although at xs size I'm happy for the button to go to another line.